# Did I find a bug in MATLAB imfilter for single precision input?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

aI found strange non-deterministic behaviour in my matlab code and I could reduce it to the following minimal code snippet:

```
   image = single(zeros(16,14));
   grad = imfilter(image, [0 0 0;0 1 0;0 0  0]);
   tcn = norm(grad(:));        
   fprintf('norm:  %f   \n', double(tcn));
```

First I do a **"clear all"**, then I run the code snippet six times and get the following output

```
norm:  107570908894816200000000000000.000000  
norm: 0.0
norm: 0.0
norm: NaN
norm: 0.0
norm: 0.0
...
```

Then the correct ouput continues for ever.
I can "restart" the wrong behaviour using "clear all".

I tested this with MATLAB 2014b and 2013a on two different computers running Windows 7.

Removing the single() cast seems to fix the problem.
Also changing the size of the input image fixes the problem with some values.
I will work around this problem using a double() cast.

However, am I missing something here, or is this a bug with imfilters single implementation?

Comment: I do a `clear all` and then copy and paste the code snippet to the MATLAB command window six times.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this error.  I have done what you have mentioned, and have done it 20 times instead of 6.  I have MATLAB R2013a running on Mac OS X 10.9.5, and I am getting a norm of `0.00000` with each invocation.  I haven't tested this on a Windows machine, but I will when I am able to.  What does `grad` and `image` look like after each invocation?

Comment: `image` looks as expected all zeros. For the wrong results `grad` has some `NaN` and some non-zero values, that may be small (4.0234) or big (1.0e+28 * 7.5022).

Comment: when you type `class(tcn)`, what it gives back?

Comment: class(tcn) is single, but as I commented to your question, this is not the problem. I fixed the question though, thank you.

Comment: @Stiefel - I just ran your code on my Windows machine at home.  I'm running Windows 7 Professional - 64 bit.  I am now able to reproduce your results.  It's funny because even though I clear my environment, the first norm I get is a large number, but that norm changes with each `clear`.  This must mean it's OS dependent as this didn't appear on my Mac OS machine.  I suggest you submit a bug report to MathWorks.  This is strange behaviour indeed!  It looks like you'll have to stick with the `double` casting for now.

Comment: Thank you rayryeng. I submitted the bug to mathworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question, since it turned out to be a real bug in Matlab.

I contacted Mathworks support and their developers confirmed the bug. The following work arounds were suggested:

I spoke with the developers and this results to be a bug in the Image Processing Toolbox.

1. Use conv2:

> > out = conv2(image,grad,'same');

Use conv2 if you are using zero-padding (default in imfilter).

2. Use double precision:

> > out = single(imfilter(double(image),grad));

3. Turn off IPP:

> > iptsetpref('UseIPPL',false);

Note that this will disable performance optimizations across a number of functions in the Image Processing Toolbox and should be used as a last resort.

Comment: Cool! Nice to know about this bug. I work in double precision anyway so this won't be a problem, but very good to know about this bug nonetheless.